# Celery Tasks executing incorrectly

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm using Celery with Django in an online game. Users build ships of various types, and a task is set to deliver them a certain time later.

As an example:

```
def buildfighter(world, amount):
    world.shipyardsinuse = F('shipyardsinuse') + 1*amount
    world.save()
    newtask.buildfighter.apply_async(args=(world.worldid,amount), eta=outcometime)
```

And my actual task code, to be executed 1 hour later:

```
def buildfighter(worldno, amount):
    world = World.objects.get(worldid=worldno)
    world.fighters = F('fighters') + amount
    world.shipyardsinuse = F('shipyardsinuse') - 1*amount
    world.save()
```

The task delivers this ships and frees the shipyards.

I keep getting *occasional* reports of users experiencing blocked shipyards and missing ships past the eta, and for the life of my I cannot figure out why! I've set up celerycam and when I go back to inspect those missing tasks, they all show as `SUCCEEDED`.

The celery parts of my settings.py:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("wawmembers.tasks", )
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 14400
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Use some logging to check that your tasks are called. You can use redis or memcache or something like this and implement some bookkeeping. I know it is kind of checking the message broker, but it will let you verify that your tasks are indeed called.
2. It might be that your database query

   world = World.objects.get(worldid=worldno)
   bring you old results, because it is used some existing transaction. Try maybe to print what you get that to verify if this is the case. You can force new transaction by trying to write before you read. Note that django 1.6 might have problems if your DB connection was idle for too long.